# Unable to pkill a subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pkill

Consider:

```py
import subprocess
import time

def run_instance():
    command = "sleep 30 >out 2>err &"
    subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, start_new_session=True)

def kill_instance():
    print(subprocess.check_output(f"pgrep -f 30", shell=True))
    subprocess.check_output(f"pkill -f 30", shell=True)

run_instance()
time.sleep(1)
kill_instance()
```

The output (run under `Ubuntu`) is:

```
b'17483\n17484\n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    kill_instance()
  File "test.py", line 10, in kill_instance
    subprocess.check_output(f"pkill -f 30", shell=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'pkill -f 30' died with <Signals.SIGTERM: 15>.
```

Why does `pkill` fail even though `pgrep` finds the process?

Comment: I suppose you're trying to kill too much processes and don't have enough permissions. On my machine `pgrep -f 30` returns 17 processes now.

Comment: Try to add a `-a` to the `pgrep` to see the process names. Likely a permission issue like @SUTerliakov said

Comment: @SUTerliakov No, it's only two processes (one of which is `pgrep` itself), just as it appears on the output in the question.  I added `-a` and got: `b'17490 sleep 30\n17491 /bin/sh -c pgrep -af 30\n'`

Comment: @dev93 Why would there be a permission issue when it's the same script that created these processes? (see my reply to @SUTerliakov)

Comment: Well, there you have your answer, your python code is succesfully sending a SIGTERM signal to your sleep ... and to itself. and that's the "error" you got.

Comment: @dev93 Not itself, but `pgrep`... In fact, if I change `pkill -f 30` for `pkill sleep`, I get the same error.

Comment: Incidentally, why use `pkill` when you have the process handle and launched it yourself?  Or is this just a demo?

Comment: Rewrite `run_instance` to `return subprocess.Popen(['sleep', '30'], stdout=open('out', 'w'), stderr=open('err', 'w'))` and you'll no longer be creating unnecessary problems for yourself that you need `pkill` to solve; instead you can just call `kill()` on that returned object.

Comment: It's possible to make it work with `shell=True` also -- take out the `&`, use the shell builtin `exec`, and switch to `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: @2e0byo It is a demo.

Answer (score 1):

### Common way

The most clean, IMO, way here is to just manage your instance within python (note you don't even need `shell=True`):

```py
import subprocess
import time


def start_instance():
    with open('err', 'w') as err, open('out', 'w') as out:
        return subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/sleep', '30'], stdout=out, stderr=err)

def kill_instance(proc):
    proc.kill()

process = start_instance()
time.sleep(1)
kill_instance(process)
```

### Your code

Disclaimer: you shouldn't be doing this in production.

You are killing your `pkill`. Here's the same with more verbose output:

```py
import subprocess
import time

def run_instance():
    command = "sleep 30 >out 2>err &"
    subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, start_new_session=True)

def kill_instance():
    print(subprocess.check_output(f"pgrep -f 30 -la", shell=True, universal_newlines=True))  # More verbose output
    subprocess.check_output(f"pkill -f 30", shell=True)

run_instance()
time.sleep(1)
kill_instance()
```

This outputs on my machine:

```
2446344 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 5434 -container-ip 172.30.0.2 -container-port 5434
2446350 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 5434 -container-ip 172.30.0.2 -container-port 5434
2446618 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.30.0.4 -container-port 8080
2446624 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 8080 -container-ip 172.30.0.4 -container-port 8080
2446657 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 5001 -container-ip 172.30.0.5 -container-port 5000
2446666 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 5001 -container-ip 172.30.0.5 -container-port 5000
2470568 kworker/u8:30-i915
2484058 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2176 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 41465 -prefMapSize 226778 -jsInitLen 277276 -parentBuildID 20220623063721 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 7462 true tab
2484060 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2177 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 41465 -prefMapSize 226778 -jsInitLen 277276 -parentBuildID 20220623063721 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 7462 true tab
2484067 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2178 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 41465 -prefMapSize 226778 -jsInitLen 277276 -parentBuildID 20220623063721 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 7462 true tab
2484121 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2179 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 41465 -prefMapSize 226778 -jsInitLen 277276 -parentBuildID 20220623063721 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 7462 true tab
2484283 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2181 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 41465 -prefMapSize 226778 -jsInitLen 277276 -parentBuildID 20220623063721 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 7462 true tab
2484293 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2182 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 41465 -prefMapSize 226778 -jsInitLen 277276 -parentBuildID 20220623063721 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 7462 true tab
2484392 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2183 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 41465 -prefMapSize 226778 -jsInitLen 277276 -parentBuildID 20220623063721 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 7462 true tab
2484394 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2184 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 41465 -prefMapSize 226778 -jsInitLen 277276 -parentBuildID 20220623063721 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 7462 true tab
2484423 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2185 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 41465 -prefMapSize 226778 -jsInitLen 277276 -parentBuildID 20220623063721 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 7462 true tab
2484442 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -parentBuildID 20220623063721 -prefsLen 41465 -prefMapSize 226778 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 7462 true socket
2484491 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2186 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 41465 -prefMapSize 226778 -jsInitLen 277276 -parentBuildID 20220623063721 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 7462 true tab
2484546 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -contentproc -childID 2187 -isForBrowser -prefsLen 41465 -prefMapSize 226778 -jsInitLen 277276 -parentBuildID 20220623063721 -appDir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 7462 true tab
2487379 sleep 30
2487381 /bin/sh -c pgrep -f 30 -la

pkill: killing pid 2446344 failed: Operation not permitted
pkill: killing pid 2446350 failed: Operation not permitted
pkill: killing pid 2446618 failed: Operation not permitted
pkill: killing pid 2446624 failed: Operation not permitted
pkill: killing pid 2446657 failed: Operation not permitted
pkill: killing pid 2446666 failed: Operation not permitted
pkill: killing pid 2470568 failed: Operation not permitted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/a.py", line 14, in <module>
    kill_instance()
  File "/tmp/a.py", line 10, in kill_instance
    subprocess.check_output(f"pkill -f 30", shell=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 524, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'pkill -f 30' died with <Signals.SIGTERM: 15>.
```

(ignore `docker` and `firefox` processes here, they're just for completeness here and to demonstrate that you're killing too much processes, ff tabs crash after this)

The interesting output part from `pgrep` here:

```
2487379 sleep 30
2487381 /bin/sh -c pgrep -f 30 -la
```

When you call `pkill`, it is a process. It will be there instead of `pgrep`, something like

```
2487379 sleep 30
2487xxx /bin/sh -c pkill -f 30
```

... and you `pkill` all matching processes. So you can kill the running instance successfully, but then kill yourself.

To demonstrate that, the following succeeds:

```py
import subprocess
import time

def run_instance():
    command = "sleep 30 >out 2>err &"
    subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True, start_new_session=True)

def kill_instance():
    print(subprocess.check_output("pgrep -f 'sleep 30' -la", shell=True, universal_newlines=True))
    subprocess.check_output("pgrep -f 'sleep 30' | grep -v $$ | xargs kill -SIGTERM", shell=True, universal_newlines=True)

run_instance()
time.sleep(1)
kill_instance()
```

Output:

```
2508440 sleep 30
2508441 /bin/sh -c pgrep -f 'sleep 30' -la
```

Sorry for that ugly pipe, maybe there is a simpler way, but Linux `pgrep` cannot exclude self (as opposed to FreeBSD, discussed [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/290553/pgrep-in-my-shell-script-not-counting-the-script-itself)). This pipe lists processes, excludes `pgrep` itself (`$$` refers to current *parent* shell, which is that runs `pgrep` here) and passes them to `kill`.

Comment: What if I need the managed process (`sleep` in the example) to persist even after the main script dies for any reason (e.g. killed from the terminal)? I was trying to solve that with the `start_new_session` argument to `subprocess.check_output`...

Comment: `Popen` is not terminated when your application quits (and even when you quit `bash` seesion, AFAIR) unless joined/killed/terminated explicitly. You can try this code without `kill_instance` call to see this behavior. But then don't use stdout/stdin files, they'll be never closed.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2251026/14401160)

Comment: Linux is neither Windows, nor FreeBSD...

Comment: Augh, sorry, I missed that linux was not explicitly named there. FreeBSD solution from there works on linux for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are vastly overcomplicating things by basically running shell scripts on top of Python.

Here's (something like) the proper solution.

```
def run_instance():
    command = ["sleep", "30"]
    return subprocess.Popen(command,
        stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

def kill_instance(proc):
    proc.kill()

proc = run_instance()
time.sleep(1)
kill_instance(proc)
```

A more complete example would `proc.wait()` if the `kill` failed for whatever reason.