# Extra processes that linger

Tags: python, subprocess

My class for handling processes, somewhat shortened for simplicity, looks like this:

```py
class LocalEngine:

    def __init__(self):
        name_to_pid = {}

    def run_instance(self, name):
        args = ... # Computing args for Popen from arguments
        with open(f"out-{name}", 'a') as out, open(f"err-{name}", 'a') as err:
            pid = \
                subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=out, stderr=err, shell=False).pid
            print(f"Created process {pid}")
            self.name_to_pid[name] = pid

    def kill_instance(self, name):
        pid = self.name_to_pid[name]
        print(f"Killing process {pid}")
        psutil.Process(pid).kill()
```

There is only one object `engine` of type `LocalEngine` and all processes are created using `engine.run_instance`. At the end, all processes are killed using `engine.kill_instance`.

Here is the relevant part of the main script's output (under Ubuntu):

```
Created process 9676
Created process 9703
Killing process 9703
Killing process 9676
```

However, this is what `ps auxfww` outputs after all processes are created:

```
root     27576  0.0  0.0    896    80 ?        S    10:33   0:00  \_ /init
meir     27577  0.0  0.0  10688  5944 pts/2    Ss   10:33   0:00      \_ -bash
meir      9667  2.2  0.0  24296 16956 pts/2    S+   15:26   0:00          \_ python -m examples.agent_assignment.run_server
meir      9668  0.3  0.0 392712 16732 pts/2    Sl+  15:26   0:00              \_ python -m examples.agent_assignment.run_server
meir      9676  1.9  0.0  24016 16340 pts/2    S+   15:26   0:00              \_ python -m src.run_backup 127.0.1.1 57785 server-1
meir      9677  3.7  0.0 392784 14648 pts/2    Sl+  15:26   0:00              |   \_ python -m src.run_backup 127.0.1.1 57785 server-1
meir      9703  8.0  0.0  28364 21084 pts/2    S+   15:26   0:00              \_ python -m examples.agent_assignment.run_client 127.0.1.1 57785 client-1 2
meir      9704 10.0  0.0 765568 18912 pts/2    Sl+  15:26   0:00                  \_ python -m examples.agent_assignment.run_client 127.0.1.1 57785 client-1 2
```

`run_server` is the main script. The two calls to `Popen` run the scripts named `run_backup` and `run_client`, respectively. The above output of `ps` shows that, for some reason, there are two processes for each call of `Popen`. Since I pass `shell=False` to `Popen`, I would not expect that to happen. Here is the output of `ps` after the processes are killed:

```
root     27575  0.0  0.0    896    80 ?        Ss   10:33   0:00 /init
root     27576  0.0  0.0    896    80 ?        S    10:33   0:00  \_ /init
meir     27577  0.0  0.0  10688  5944 pts/2    Ss+  10:33   0:00      \_ -bash
meir      9677  0.1  0.0 466516 14736 pts/2    Sl   15:26   0:00      \_ python -m src.run_backup 127.0.1.1 57785 server-1
meir      9704  0.0  0.0 749176 21088 pts/2    Sl   15:26   0:00      \_ python -m examples.agent_assignment.run_client 127.0.1.1 57785 client-1 2
```

What are these extra processes that linger? How do I prevent them from being created?

**EDIT AFTER FEEDBACK:**

Based on the reply by @AKX I changed the `kill_instance` method. I cannot switch to storing process objects instead of pid's due to the requirement of unpickling by another process.

```py
    def kill_instance(self, name):
        # Process tree with full commands: ps auxfww
        pid = self.name_to_pid[name]
        print(f"Terminating process {pid}")
        proc = psutil.Process(pid)
        proc.terminate()
        print(f"Waiting for process {proc} to terminate")
        try:
            proc.wait(timeout=10)
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            print(f"Process {pid} did not terminate in time, killing it")
            proc.kill()
```

The exception is not triggered, but there are still processes lingering as in the original question...

**UPDATE:**

Got it! The second process appears because of starting `multiprocessing` manager. Now the question is how to terminate both the process and the manager...

Comment: To repeat the feedback on [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73097986/unable-to-pkill-a-subprocess): why are you not simply storing the actual `Popen` object and then eventually calling its `kill` method?

Comment: @tripleee Because I need to pickle `engine` and the proc object is not pickleable.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You can customize pickling with `__getstate__` if that's your issue.

Comment: @AKX The process that unpickles needs to be able to kill these processes, so it must work based on pid anyway. Would `terminate` not work with the approach based on storing pid as the dictionary value?

Comment: Sure, `Process(pid).terminate()` would work. You did never originally mention that there's a separate process that needs to unpickle anything, though, which does change things.

Comment: This sounds like a massive [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) once again. Guessing a bit as to what your actual requirements are, probably pickle (or otherwise just save) the PID:s, which are simple integers. You'd still have to figure out somehow if a PID could have been reused after a reboot or something.

Comment: @AKX You are right, my implementation begged the question, so I should have mentioned it. In any case, using `terminate` does not seem to make a difference (see the update in the question)...

Comment: @tripleee Please see the last update. The real question becomes: how to terminate a process that started a manager... I wonder if I should submit another question to keep things clean.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You could set up a signal handler in your manager-starting processes to clean things up... cleanly. Or send `SIGINT` instead of `SIGTERM`; that should propagate into a KeyboardInterrupt.

Answer (score 1):

I think using `kill()` (the `SIGKILL` signal) is a bit problematic; you should try to `terminate()` (`SIGTERM`) the processes first.

Also, it'd be better to do that via the `Popen` object, so Python's side of the `Popen` has time to deal with things:

```
import subprocess


class LocalEngine:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name_to_proc: dict[str, subprocess.Popen] = {}

    def run_instance(self, name):
        args = ...  # Computing args for Popen from arguments
        with open(f"out-{name}", 'a') as out, open(f"err-{name}", 'a') as err:
            proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=out, stderr=err, shell=False)
            print(f"Created process {proc.pid}")
            self.name_to_proc[name] = proc

    def kill_instance(self, name, timeout=10):
        proc = self.name_to_proc[name]
        print(f"Killing process {proc}")
        proc.terminate()
        print(f"Waiting for process {proc} to terminate")
        try:
            proc.wait(timeout=timeout)
        except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
            print(f"Process {proc} did not terminate in time, killing it")
            proc.kill()
```

Comment: You did not answer the question: "What are these extra processes that linger?" Also, can you explain why your solution does not have this problem?

Comment: `terminate` (SIGTERM) gives the processes a chance to clean up. The lingering processes are probably subprocesses that weren't `wait`ed on, so they get moved to their parent to wait on.

Comment: But why were these subprocesses created in the first place?

Comment: How should we know what the code in those spawned processes does?

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately, it's too large to show. `run_client` does spawn `multiprocessing.Process`, but `run_backup` does not do anything like that as far as I can think...

Comment: I updated the question with the code I tried based on your reply. There are still lingering processes...